# How can I tell an HTML5 video element to only use the left sound channel?

Tags: html5-video

How can I tell an HTML5 `video` element to only use the left sound channel? Is there an attribute on the `video` tag that will allow me to do this?

Comment: There is no option available for left/right channel, a full list of options can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video)

Comment: Thank you! but is anyway to change to video channel ,I mean like javascript or if i use flash to play video?

Comment: You can either create your own Flash Video Player (tutorials can be found on the web but keep in mind that Flash is already near-dead) or mofidy the video files themselves to only include the left channel. Btw, why would you want to get rid of the right channel?

Comment: Hey,I just want to design a singing system,so i only need the left sound channel